# Unix: How to get substring using indexOf kind of utility

Tags: shell, unix

I have a variable in shellscript whose value is say:
`PagingControl.labelLoadMore==>Value:Show More...`
Something like
`str = "PagingControl.labelLoadMore==>Value:Show More..."`

I want to get substring from starting index to where I find "==>Value:"

In Java and Javascript we have function like: 
`str.substring(0, str.indexOf("==>Value:"))`

How can we similarly do in shellscript ?
I have some idea of using `cut` and `sed` but not very good at them.
Can someone please give me hint.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following ***sed*** approach:

```
str="PagingControl.labelLoadMore==>Value:Show More..."
echo $str | sed 's/\(.*\)==>Value.*/\1/'
```

The output:

`PagingControl.labelLoadMore`

---

It'll grab a substring from the start of the input string till encountering `==>Value`